# asp.net user control scroolIntoView is scrolling entire page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, scroll

I there

I'm using an asp.net user control with a tree view. 
When I load the page I want to scrool the user control to the selected node in the tree view.
I'm using js function .ScrollIntoView(true).
But this is scrolling the entire page (not only what is inside the user control)

here's my code

```
//js
function ScroolToFirstSelectedCheckBox(ctrlId) {

    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
        var tree = document.getElementById(ctrlId + '_MyTreeView');

        var checkBoxes = tree.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var checkBoxesCount = checkBoxes.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxesCount; i++) {
            if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
                checkBoxes[i].scrollIntoView(true);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    );
}

//aspx.cs
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), 
                                             "ScrollToSelectedCheckBox", 
                           string.Format("ScroolToFirstSelectedCheckBox('{0}')", 
                           this.UniqueID), 
                           true);
```

How can I keep the parent page scroll position but continue to set user controll position where I want?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

ok, simply changed

```
checkBoxes[i].scrollIntoView(true);
```

with

```
checkBoxes[i].scrollIntoView(false);
```

That's it!!!

=P